# Como acessar um vetor dentro de um obejto em PHP e inserir os dados no banco de dados MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, array, http

Gostaria de saber como acessar o vetor de endereços dentro deste objeto:

[image: foto do vetor]

E inserir os atributos dentro de uma tabela no MySQL, estou fazendo da seguinte maneira

```
 foreach ($this->endereco as $elemento) {
            $nome = $elemento['nome'];
            $logradouro = $elemento['logradouro'];
            $bairro = $elemento['bairro'];
            $numero = $elemento['numero'];
            $cidade = $elemento['cidade'];
            $estado = $elemento['estado'];
            $cep = $elemento['cep'];
            echo $nome;
            $query = $query."('".$nome."','".$logradouro."','".$bairro."','".$numero."','".$cidade."', '".$estado."', '".$cep."', '".$id."'),";
        }
```

Contudo a query fica da seguinte maneira:

```
INSERT INTO endereco_juridica(nome, logradouro, bairro, numero, cidade, estado, CEP, juridica_id_juridica) VALUES('campus pici','','','','', '', '', ''),('sede','','','','', '', '', ''),('','AV DA UNIVERSIDADE','','','', '', '', ''),('','R VERGUEIRO','','','', '', '', ''),('','','','2853','', '', '', ''),('','','','123','', '', '', ''),('','','BENFICA','','', '', '', ''),('','','mucambo','','', '', '', ''),('','','','','FORTALEZA', '', '', ''),('','','','','SAO PAULO', '', '', ''),('','','','','', 'Selecione o estado', '', ''),('','','','','', 'SP', '', ''),('','','','','', '', '60.020-181', ''),('','','','','', '', '34213123', ''),"
```

Faço a coleta dos dados vindo do forumlário dessa froma:

```
foreach ($_POST['nome'] as $nome) {
    $empresa->endereco[] = array('nome' => $nome);
}

foreach ($_POST['logradouro'] as $logradouro) {
    $empresa->endereco[] = array('logradouro' => $logradouro);
}

foreach ($_POST['numero'] as $numero) {
    $empresa->endereco[] = array('numero' => $numero);
}


foreach ($_POST['bairro'] as $bairro) {
    $empresa->endereco[] = array('bairro' => $bairro);
}


foreach ($_POST['cidade'] as $cidade) {
    $empresa->endereco[] = array('cidade' => $cidade);
}

foreach ($_POST['estado'] as $estado) {
    $empresa->endereco[] = array('estado' => $estado);
}

foreach ($_POST['cep'] as $cep) {
    $empresa->endereco[] = array('cep' => $cep);
}
```

Se alguem tiver alguma ideia ficarei mto grato, ja tentei de tudo.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver o problema, estava fazendo a construção do vetor de forma erradada. Está funcionando dessa maneira:

```
$tam = 0;
foreach ($_POST['nome'] as $nomepost) {
    $nome = $nomepost;
    $logradouro = $_POST['logradouro'][$tam];
    $numero = $_POST['numero'][$tam];
    $bairro = $_POST['bairro'][$tam];
    $cidade = $_POST['cidade'][$tam];
    $estado = $_POST['estado'][$tam];
    $cep = $_POST['cep'][$tam];  
    $empresa->endereco[] = array('nome' => $nome, 'logradouro' => $logradouro, 'numero'=> $numero, 'bairro' => $bairro, 'cidade' => $cidade, 'estado'=> $estado, 'cep'=> $cep);
    $tam++;
}
```